# IMG in DIV creating extra space at the bottom only in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

HTML:

```
<div class="dropShadow">
    <img src="images/headerimage" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.dropShadow {
    background-image: url('dropshadow.png');
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 19px; /* the height of the shadow */
}
```

however, on Firefox its all fine, where as on Chrome and IE, there is a small white space between the bottom of the image and the top of the positioned background image. I removed all the white space from around it, but I'm not sure what rules to try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write **vertical-align:top** or **display:block** in your IMG. Write like this:

```
img{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```